# Tag wiki reviewing

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

What is the general criteria for approving (or rejecting) a tag wiki edit that is the creation of a new tag wiki and a new tag, about proprietary APIs or similar?

Specifically, I was given this review:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2260061
which is a review of the [vapix](/questions/tagged/vapix) tag wiki.  That tag was just created by the user, and added to a few existing (and old) questions.

I don't know anything about the specific subject matter, but given the very small niche that tag occupies I doubt many reviewers would.  What would constitute a reason to object to the edit?  I felt very conflicted here; on the one hand, the user seems very reliable and certainly does a lot on SO (two gold badges, almost 4k rep, so nearly able to do this himself anyway); on the other hand, this is a tag for a proprietary API, and so could be an attempt at self-promotion (not knowing the user, I haven't a clue if there's a link there).  Certainly the combination of creating a tag and adding it to a couple of very old questions seems a bit suspicious.

Comment: I ended up voting to reject, as it has pretty close to plagiarized content (a few words changed but nothing major), but my question is a bit more general as to the tag's appropriateness.

Comment: Rejected too. There are a few people who create a *lot* of tag-wikis for non-tags...

Comment: I did read the 'How do I review...' question, but wanted to specifically ask this for 'proprietary' tags - ie, things that might be back-door advertising or self-promotion.